# Смена сессии при каждом обновлении страницы

Tags: php, сессия

Происходит смена сессии при каждом обновлении страницы. Напрямую открываю - сессия стабильна. При переходе с того же текстового html файла с рабочего стола на сайт - каждый раз меняется и при обновлении тоже меняется сессия (если был переход).

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_secure','On');
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

Comment: вы ожидаете одну сессию на локальном сайте и на хостинге, или что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.ini

```
session.cookie_samesite = Strict
```

заменил на Lax

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/421486)

Comment: @Coder ну мне это помогло. Это ответ